# Angular 9: @angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines

I know, there are 2/3 similar questions, but not a solution for me

We added two packages and everything works fine locally, but not in our (Azure) devops pipeline. I made sure to use the same node version (10.17) and a fresh npm install...

"@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4"
"ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0"

These are the errors:

```
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238150Z ERROR in [96m../../../Packages/npm/moondesk-web/node_modules/@ng-idle/core/lib/idle.d.ts[0m:[93m66[0m:[93m25[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2694: [0mNamespace '"D:/a/1/s/illustrator/extension/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238264Z 
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238363Z [7m66[0m     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<Idle>;
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238430Z [7m  [0m [91m                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238509Z [96m../../../Packages/npm/moondesk-web/node_modules/@ng-idle/core/lib/localstorage.d.ts[0m:[93m10[0m:[93m25[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2694: [0mNamespace '"D:/a/1/s/illustrator/extension/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238534Z 
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238613Z [7m10[0m     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LocalStorage>;
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238652Z [7m  [0m [91m                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238712Z [96m../../../Packages/npm/moondesk-web/node_modules/@ng-idle/core/lib/localstorageexpiry.d.ts[0m:[93m16[0m:[93m25[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2694: [0mNamespace '"D:/a/1/s/illustrator/extension/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238764Z 
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5238822Z [7m16[0m     static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<LocalStorageExpiry>;
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5240164Z [7m  [0m [91m                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~[0m
2019-11-12T19:58:21.5240268Z [96m../../../Packages/npm/moondesk-web/node_modules/ngx-cookie-service/cookie-service/cookie.service.d.ts[0m:[93m48[0m:[93m25[0m - [91merror[0m[90m TS2694: [0mNamespace '"D:/a/1/s/illustrator/extension/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDef'.
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Angular 10.2.5 with smart-webcomponents-angular. Works on local but fails with same error in Azure DevOps. I tried all smart-webcomponents-angular version from 8 to 10 with no success. Did you find a solution for this?